# Quicksort tree maximum and minimum height

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

In quicksort, if we always split the left part to size `a` and the right part to size `(n-1-a)`,  then what is the minimum and the maximum height of the recursion tree?

Comment: In quicksort, you can not fix the size of left part and right part. It depends upon pivot element and its position. so, would you please elaborate what do you want exactly ?

Comment: @BishalGautam Technically, one could use the quick select algorithm to pick a pivot element at any desired index, so the operation isn't impossible.

Comment: @merlyn That makes pivot selection worse than O(1)

Comment: @EmilVikström As long as pivot selection is O(n), it doesn't harm the overall complexity. In fact, you could quickselect the median and use it as pivot for guaranteed worst case complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684680/maximum-and-minimum-depth-of-quicksort

Comment: imagine we can fix the number of the left part , another way to ask this, if you always split the current number of elements to 4 elements to the left subtree and the remaining (if any) on the right subtree ,What is the maximum and minimum branch height in your tree

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort worst case occurs when the input array is **already sorted**(*either in non-decreasing or non-increasing order*) and we always pick either first or last element as pivot(*partition is not randomized*).

Take for example input array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Suppose we pick the leftmost element to be the pivot. So recursion tree build up is like:

```
   n
  /  \
 1    n-1(2,3,4,5)
```

Similarly 2 will be picked up as pivot , making the tree:

```
   n
  /  \
 1    n-1(2,3,4,5)
     /   \
    1    n-2(3,4,5)
```

Observing the pattern, the height of the tree will be **O(N)**, also at each level 
**partition** algorithm will take **O(N)** time, leading to total time = **O(N^2)**

Best height of recursion tree is **O(logN)**, this occurs when the median(middle element) gets picked as pivot always.

Comment: uhm ...right, but this is only the answer for a = 1 what about the general case?

Comment: @SaiBot That does not concern the maximum or minimum height of recrusion tree and hence not discussed.

Comment: Yes it does, e.g., if a = n/2 then max height = min height  = ceil(log(n))

Comment: @SaiBot Already wrote answer for that. Read it. By the way, do read about BIG O notation, ceils and floors are not important.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but there is no mention of complexity. As I understand it the question is about the min and max depth of the recursion tree which can be given exactly given a.

Comment: I would have expected an answer closer to this one http://www.slader.com/discussion/question/suppose-that-the-splits-at-every-level-of-quicksort-are-in-the-proportion-1/

Comment: complexity isn't the main problem here, I want to know how the tree would look like if we assume that each time we will divide the left part to size a and the remaining to the right